# -bash: /usr/local/bin/kops: cannot execute binary file

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kops

Any help or hint would greatly appreciated.
I am using Windows 11 Professional.

I am connect to AWS and when I type the command "kops" I get the below error message.

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-126 ~]$ curl -Lo kops https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kops/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4)/kops-darwin-amd64

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

```
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

100  157M  100  157M    0     0  98.8M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  119M

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-126 ~]$ chmod +x kops

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-126 ~]$ sudo mv kops /usr/local/bin/kops

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-126 ~]$ kops

-bash: /usr/local/bin/kops: cannot execute binary file

[image]

Comment: You're trying to run the macosx binary on Linux. Download the linux version.

Answer (score 3):

You're only using Windows 11 as a ssh client - it's not doing anything for Kubernetes.

As @jordanm indicates you're trying to download the MacOS version.  Change your command to:

```
curl -Lo kops https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kops/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4)/kops-linux-amd64
```

to get the Linux version